# Checking straight sequences in arrays

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a method (`public bool Seq_Check(int[] A, int k)`) that checks whether an array `A` contains numbers `1,2,...,k` (every number from `1` to `k` at least once) and no other numbers.

So, for `myArr1` and `myArr2`, it should return `true` and `false` respectively, which it does, but wrongly shows `true` for the 3rd array.

Can someone please help me find the bug here?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ArrayChecker
{
    class Program
    {
        /// The program's main entry point.
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Input arrays are assumed to be in non-decreasing order.
            int[] myArr1 = new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 3, 3 };
            int[] myArr2 = new int[] { 1, 1, 3 };
            int[] myArr3 = new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1 };

            // Printing to console True & False respectively.
            Console.WriteLine( Seq_Check(myArr1, 3) );
            Console.WriteLine( Seq_Check(myArr2, 2) );
            Console.WriteLine( Seq_Check(myArr3, 6) );

            // Prevent the console window from closing.
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        /// This method checks whether array A contains numbers 1,2,...,k
        /// (every number from 1 to k exactly once) and no other numbers.
        public static bool Seq_Check(int[] A, int k)
        {
            int n = A.Length;

            for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
            {
                if ( A[i]+1 < A[i+1] )
                    return false;
            }

            if ( A[0] != 1 && A[n-1] != k )
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does *order* matter? E.g. is `[5, 3, 2, 4, 1]` a correct array `(k == 5)`?

Comment: I didn't get why it should return false for myArr4.

Comment: Have you stepped through `Seq_check` to see which of the `return false` statements is executing?

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz - The second parameter `k` is 6 so it should be `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` but is actually `1,2,3,3,4,5,6` (from my understanding)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: Given that the arrays are ascending, the order will inevitably be ascending too.

Comment: @keyboardP same for myArr3, it has three 1's.

Comment: Why should it return false for the fourth Array? It contains every number from 1 to 6 at least once. Why is containing two 3 not allowed?

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz - It's from the first index of the sequence so it's a subset starting at any point

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz: Because there is not `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` but instead `1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6` so there is more than one `3`.

Comment: @keyboardP Based on your comment `myArr3` should also returns false but it is true!

Comment: @S.Akbari - There is a 1,2,3,4,5,6 sequence in ascending order. The preceding 1's are irrelevant

Comment: Yes, the preceding 1's are irrelevant.

Comment: Your requirements are incorrect then. You say "every number from `1` to `k` **at least once**" which `myArr4` follows. I think you mean "in order, exactly once, except at the beginning", apparently..

Comment: Is `6,1,2,3,4,5,6` supposed to return true or false? What about `6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1`?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: You are right. Thanks for pointing that out. I will add an edit...

Comment: @PrestonGuillot: Both should be false. The order should be `1,2,3,...,k`

Comment: There's an ordered sequence of 1..6 in both those arrays, your problem statement needs more definition.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot: Thank you. I edited the problem. Does it make sense now?

Comment: @ChrisF: I still do not feel confident debugging that way. Do you know of a very simple tutorial on how to use stepping through? I am still elementary...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main check in the for loop needs to be changed:

```
if (A[i] + 1 < A[i+1] )
    return false;
```

First, you need to check the order, so you need to check if an element with higher index is larger than previous one:

```
if (A[i] >= A[i+1])
    return false;
```

Since you don't mind if elements are equal in the beginning or at the end of the series, you need to add another check to avoid returning false in those cases:

```
bool inSequence = A[i] != 1 || A[i] == k;
if (A[i] > A[i+1] || (A[i] == A[i+1] && inSequence))
  return false;
```

Here, we check if we started/ended series passed duplicates or not, if we are still in sequence, duplicates not allowed so A[i+1] == A[i] should return false.

```
public static bool Seq_Check(int[] A, int k)
{
    int n = A.Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        bool inSequence = A[i] != 1 || A[i] == k;
        if (A[i] > A[i+1] || (A[i] == A[i+1] && inSequence))
            return false;
        }

    }
    if ( A[0] != 1 && A[n-1] != k )
        return false;
    else
        return true;     
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
        public static bool Seq_Check(int[] A, int k)
        {
            int n = A.Length;
            if (A[0] != 1 || A[n - 1] != k)//no need to go through array if it is already bad
                return false;

            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
            {
                if (A[i] + 1 < A[i + 1])
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

You were using && instead of || when checking if A[0]=1 and A[n-1]=k. This means that as long as either condition was true, the function would return true. You want it to be that if either condition is true, the function should return false.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Linq, you can use the Range() and Distinct() and Exclude() to accomplish your task... make Linq do the work for you.

Comment: Thank you. I now realize how imperative it is to start learning Linq...

Answer (score 0):

The reason it returns `true` for the 3rd array is because `A[0] != 1 && A[n-1] != k` is `false`.

I'll break it up.

**A[0] != 1** Let's call it `X`

The first place in the array is indeed 1, so return `true`.

**A[n-1] != k** Let's call it `Y`

The last place is not 6, so return `false`.

Ergo, `X && Y` is `false`.

Should it be `A[0] != 1 || A[n-1] != k`??

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to see if there is a continuous range from 1 to K, that repeating numbers don't matter unless the number is in the middle of the range.

So for `[ 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 1]` the cases for **K** being `[2,3,4]` would pass, but `[5, 6]` would fail, because 4 is repeated it breaks the chain of the continuous range.

For this I would start backwards and look for instances of **K**, from there start count backwards and return true if I am able to get to **1**

```
public bool Seq_Check(int[] elems, int k)
{
    for(int i=elems.Length;i>0;i--)
    {
       //we found the first element we are looking for
       //so need to start looking for the rest of the sequence
       if(elems[i]==k)
       {
            // don't create a new index, we can reuse i
            int curr = k-1;
            for(;i>0 && curr>0;i--)
            {
                if(elems[i]!=curr) 
                {
                     if(elems[i]==k)
                     {
                         //reinitialize if we found K again
                         curr=k-1;
                         continue;
                     }
                     break;
                }

                curr--;
            }

            // if the curr value is 0 then 
            // we found all the elements
            if(curr == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
       }
    }

    //no matching sequence was found so return false
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d7yyR7) give me the same result as your. The third array is [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1], sorted version is [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]. And it really contains all numbers in range [1, 6]. What's wrong?:

```
namespace SequenceCheck
{
    using System;
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int[] myArr1 = new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 3, 3};
            int[] myArr2 = new int[] { 1, 1, 3 };
            int[] myArr3 = new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1 };

            // Printing to console True & False respectively.
            Console.WriteLine(Seq_Check(myArr1, 3));
            Console.WriteLine(Seq_Check(myArr2, 2));
            Console.WriteLine(Seq_Check(myArr3, 6));

        }
        public static bool Seq_Check(int[] A, int k)
        {
            // TODO Check for corner cases!

            // Let's at first sort the numbers
            Array.Sort(A);

            int start = 1, end = k;
            // If the first element is not equal to start, something wrong with sequence
            if (A[0] != start) return false;

            // If we here it means we checked 1, let go further
            int expected = start + 1;
            int currUnique = A[0];

            for (int i = 1; i < A.Length; i++)
            {
                // Is it new unique number?
                if (A[i] != A[i - 1])
                {
                    currUnique = A[i];
                    // Compare with expected and check is there any other numbers?
                    if (currUnique != expected || expected > end)
                        return false;
                    expected++;
                }

            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```